# htaccess doesn't redirect to the right website in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I decided to switch to a single website to multi-website (called network in wordpress). I followed this documentation :
  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

First, I followed this documentation
  - https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

In order not to have my files in the root of `~/public_html`. I called the folder : `WordPress` and I changed my .htaccess.

At this point everything worked fine.

I followed the doc till the end, so I added :

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

And I replaced the old `~/public_html/.htaccess` by

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) WordPress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ WordPress/$1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

All this code is code that wordpress told me to write.

The problem now is that when I go on the main page : `mysite.com` I see :

[image]

How I can modify my htacess (or other) to view the main page of the website ?

Thanks

edit: this url `mysite.com/wp-admin` works

Answer (score 0):

Multisite is meant to run multiple blogs in the same WordPress install. Your files should still be in the public_html directory - unless you want your site be accessed via domain.com/WordPress.

So, all of your files should be directly in public_html. Then you can go back to your dashboard and finish setting up Multisite. You can create new websites under Dashboard -> My sites.

Comment: The wordpress documentation says : If you plan to run WordPress out of its own directory, do that before activating Multisite. Is that I do with my "WordPress"..

Comment: Alright. Any reason you want to run WordPress outside of it's own directory?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, when you enter ***mysite.com/WordPress*** is what you want to appear when you enter ***mysite.com***? If yes, then:

> Verify the Profile In your Administration Panels go to Settings >
>   General . Here you will verify that the changes you made in Changing
>   the URL above, are correct. Verify that the reference in your
>   WordPress Address (URL) contains the new address. Verify that the
>   reference in your Site Address (URL) contains the new address. If you
>   have made changes, click Save Changes.

from https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL